# Without specifying a generic type, method does not return a list of elements, but simply a list

Tags: java, generics

I am having a slight inconvenience when working with generics in Java. Please consider the following code:

```
/**
 * MyElement class is simply a wrapper for a generic object.
 */

public static class MyElement<T> {
    public final T OBJ;

    public MyElement(T obj) {
        this.OBJ = obj;
    }
}

/**
 * MyElementList contains an array list of MyElements of the given type, T.
 * This represents a class that uses a list of MyElements of a certain type,
 * and this list can be accessed in an unmodifiable format.
 */

public static class MyElementList<T> {

    //Properties
    private List<MyElement<T>> elementList = new ArrayList();

    //CTOR
    public MyElementList(List<MyElement<T>> initElements) {
        elementList.addAll(initElements);
    }

    //Getter
    public List<MyElement<T>> getElements() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(elementList);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //New list of elements
    //Notice that I did not explicitly specify the type for 'MyElement'
    List<MyElement> theElements = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
                new MyElement[] {
                    new MyElement("E 1"),
                    new MyElement("E 2"),
                    new MyElement("E 3")
                }
            ));

    //Also notice I did not explicitly specify the type for 'MyElementList'
    MyElementList theList = new MyElementList(theElements);

    //The following does not work.
    //It seems to not work because theList.getElements() returns a 'List'
    //not necessarily a 'List<MyElement>' which is what I would expect it to
    //return...
    //Why???

    for(MyElement e : theList.getElements()) {
        System.out.println(e.OBJ.toString());
    }

    //Currently my work around is to do the following, but I do not like 
    //having to introduce another variable, and I would rather just do the 
    //one above

    List<MyElement> listOfElements = theList.getElements();
    for(MyElement e : listOfElements) {
        System.out.println(e.OBJ.toString());
    }

    //How come the first 'for-each' loop method does not work?
    //Is there anyway I could get it to work?
    //THANK YOU!
}
```

In the main method, if I don't specify the type parameter for 'MyElementList' the 'getElements()' method only returns a 'List', not a 'List<MyElement>'. This is inconvenient because if I want to iterate through each 'MyElement' I need to introduce another variable as a temporary list, shown in the code.

- Why doesn't the 'getElements()' method return a 'List<MyElement>'?
- Without making significant changes to 'MyElementList' Is there anything I can do to fix this?
- Is this a bad design practice?

The IDE I am using is Netbeans 7.2

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Thank you all for your quick responses. I am very impressed with the community here.  I have concluded the following:

- If a generic hint is not specified, Java ignores ALL other associated generic hints for a class - which is kind of lame, but I can live with it.
- When using generics, it is a best practice to actually specify the generic type when creating an instance of the class. This seems to be the most object oriented solution.

Thanks again!

Comment: What can't you specify the parameter of the classes `MyElement` and `MyElementList` when instantiate them?

Comment: Bottom line is: mixing generics and raw types is not a good idea. When you start mixing, all the generic information is removed, including the `<MyElement>` part I think.

Comment: @assylias in that case the second should also give error?

Comment: @sp00m It looks like thats what I'm going to have to do. I wanted the option to not have to specify the generics because I have a 'View' class which uses 'MyElementList' as a model, and it doesn't matter what the type of 'MyElement' is but simply uses the the string representation of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `MyElementList` to look like

```
public static class MyElementList<T extends MyElement> {

  //Properties
  private List<T> elementList = new ArrayList<T>();

  //CTOR
  public MyElementList(List<T> initElements) {
      elementList.addAll(initElements);
  }

  //Getter
  public List<T> getElements() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(elementList);
  }
}
```

It should work.

**EDIT** Generics can be seen as compile time hints in Java, since Java erasure will convert generics to Object. Updating your class as above will tell the compiler only elements which extend `MyElement` fit the list and `for(MyElement e : theList.getElements())` will work.

**EDIT 2** As pointed out by others (sorry, I didn't see it at first glance) also change the raw declaration to:

```
MyElementList<MyElement> theList = new MyElementList<MyElement>(theElements);
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. As mentioned by others, it appears that when a generic type is not specified Java ignores all other generic hints, which is unfortunate. This solution allows me to keep the generics at the 'MyElementList' level, while ignoring them at the 'MyElement' level, which is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```java
for(MyElement e : theList.getElements()) {
    System.out.println(e.OBJ.toString());
}
```

you could use

```java
for (Iterator<MyElement> it = theList.getElements().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    MyElement e = it.next();
    System.out.println(e.next().OBJ.toString());
}
```

which makes your compiler compliant.

But I would prefer to specify the types that your classes require when instantiating/accessing them (and your compiler too, I guess `;)`).

Answer (score 1):

Te first does not work because `getElements` returns a `List<?>` for the raw type

The second works because you assigned it to a `List<MyElement>`, ignoring the warning. Ignoring was ok because you know what it contains, but the compiler doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't the `getElements()` method return a `List<MyElement>`

Because `MyElement` is typed!

> Without making significant changes to `MyElementList` Is there
>   anything I can do to fix this?

You can probably use a wildcard:

```
List<MyElement<?>> someList = getElements();
```